# "vim /foo:123 -c 'normal! zz'" should open the file '/foo' at line 123 with the cursor centered

Tags: argument-list

When I search for a text with `grep` it gives the filename followed by a colon and a line number likethis, and then I just double click `/foo:123:bar` with the mouse:

```
$ grep -rn bar /
/foo:123:bar
```

Then I want to open that file at the line number with the cursor centered vertically.
I have tried with adding this script to ~/.vimrc without luck but it looks somehow close.

```
if argc() >= 1 && argv(0) =~ ':'
  let filename = matchstr(argv(0), '^[^:]\+')
  let line_number = matchstr(argv(0), ':\d\+')
  let line_number = tr(line_number, ':', ' ')
  "echo "Filename: " . filename . ", line: " . line_number . ", (" . argv(0) .")"
  if filereadable(filename)
    execute 'edit ' . filename
    filetype detect
    execute line_number
    normal! zz
  else
    echo "File not found: " . filename . " (" . argv(0) .")"
  endif
endif
```

I could do it with `bash` but it is not that convenient:

```
#! /bin/bash
if [[ $1 =~ ^(.*):([0-9]+) ]]
then
    vim "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" +${BASH_REMATCH[2]} -c 'normal! zz'
else
    vim $@
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Reminder that comments are for requesting clarification, guiding the author to improve the post, or for relevant minor or transient information. See https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you have with your solution is that at the moment the `.vimrc` is executed Vim is not fully ready to execute some of the command on the buffer (in particular the `zz` command).

Here is what you could do:

```
function! OpenFile()
  if argc() >= 1 && argv(0) =~ ':'
    let filename = matchstr(argv(0), '^[^:]\+')
    let line_number = matchstr(argv(0), ':\d\+')
    let line_number = tr(line_number, ':', ' ')
    "echo "Filename: " . filename . " (" . argv(0) .")"
    if filereadable(filename)
      execute 'edit ' . filename
      filetype detect
      execute line_number
      normal! zz
    else
      echo "File not found: " . filename . " (" . argv(0) .")"
    endif
  endif
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call OpenFile()
```

It delays the execution of your script after Vim is fully initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea: use `:grep`. After `:grep -r bar /` (`-n` is implied by the default `grepprg`), the quickfix list would have the entry for `/foo` at line 123, your cursor would be there, and you can press `zz` yourself.